# Regex matching a series of letters NOT in a word

Tags: c#, regex

This should turn out to be a fairly simple Regex, but I'm no expert in it. I am trying to match a sequence of specific letters, but I do not want them to match if its part of a whole word. I need to only capture the `STA` letters. Here's an example:

```
My Regex: [Ss][Tt][Aa]

STA         -- Should Match
sta         -- Should Match
Start       -- Should NOT match
sta rt      -- Should Match
rt sta      -- Should Match
rtsta       -- Should NOT Match
```

Can someone help me out here please? This is C# .NET Regex, if it matters.

Comment: @HenryShen -- That didn't work Henry, because my `STA` can be anywhere in a line and I think the caret sign matches at the beginning

Comment: Use the word Boundary \b instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *word boundary* `\b` markers [to match only whole words](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b[Ss][Tt][Aa]\b
```

Comment: To clarify, `\b` is a zero-width item that occurs between word characters `\w` and non-word characters `\W`.

Comment: @Li-aungYip This is correct - it is explained in depth in the link posted in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the blue link colour. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might consider using regex options, like so:

```
new Regex("\bsta\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Case-insensitive match is imprudent when dealing with Unicode. :)

Comment: Did not know that. Is it in so in certain languages only? icemanind's pattern appears to use ASCII only (of course, he told that's just an example).

Comment: In Python, at least, the meaning of "uppercase characters" changes depending on the user's locale. (Thought exercise: what is `"Главное в новостях".upper()` if you're English vs. if you're Russian?) There's a similar problem with `\w`: If you're in Russia, `\w` means a completely different set of characters to the English `[a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Hmm... that actually looks like very non-unicode, code-page-like behavior. Don't have any experience with regex-processing non-english, still this might be something to know and not forget about...

Comment: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) Because canonical regular expressions support Unicode whereas ECMAScript does not, character classes in ECMAScript have a more limited syntax, and some character class language elements have a different meaning. For example, ECMAScript does not support language elements such as the Unicode category or block elements \p and \P. Similarly, the \w element, which matches a word character, is equivalent to the [a-zA-Z_0-9] character class when using ECMAScript and [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}] when using canonical behavior

Comment: On the other hand: "The IgnoreCase option, or the i inline option, provides case-insensitive matching. By default, the casing conventions of the current culture are used." So, you're right.

Comment: Good research. I would read all of that as "be paranoid any time you're dealing with Unicode" (and in this international world, *everything* should be Unicode...)